# How to remove redundant/unused dependencies from package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I know [it has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22675725/1048572), but [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) doesn't seem to work for me at all. It gives me a ton of false alerts aparts from having to configure it for "config-only" libs like babel, eslint etc.

What is your approach if you get a task like it? Is there any best practice you could recommend me?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `yarn autoclean` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It looks like it only removes redundant files from the node_modules. What I'm looking for, is something that also removes those from my package.json, or at least lists out deps that are not used anywhere.

Comment: the long way which may be the surest way, is to delete node_modules run the app and slowly add the deps back in as needed till the app runs. I would just say keep track of the versions that were used cuz you dont wanna introduce any breaking changes doing this.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm hoping for a senior javascript wizard seeing this, who could hand me a silver-bullet:)

Comment: This is a cool tool to develop if it does not exist ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check).

```sh
npm i -g npm-check
```

Then enter the directory of you project and run the tool

```sh
cd my-app
npm-check


some-package   NOTUSED?
             To remove this package: npm uninstall --save some-package
```

Comment: `npm-check` appears to just use `depcheck` internally for the unused package test, and in my testing the exact same false positives appear in each.

Answer (score 1):

We use `depcheck` with Python to isolate the package.json `dependencies` key.

```py
import json
from sys import platform
from subprocess import run

div = "=================================="
use_shell = platform == "win32"

print(f"\nFinding unused dependencies\n{div}\n")

cmd = ["npx", "depcheck", "--json"]
depcheck_result = run(cmd, shell=use_shell, capture_output=True, text=True)

unused_dependencies = json.loads(depcheck_result.stdout)["dependencies"]
if len(unused_dependencies) > 0:
    print(f"Found these unused dependencies\n{div}")
    print(*unused_dependencies, sep="\n")

    affirmative_responses = {"y", "yes", "Y", "YES", ""}
    response = input(f"{div}\n\nRemove all? [yes] ").lower() in affirmative_responses

    if response == True:
        cmd = ["yarn", "remove", *unused_dependencies]
        run(cmd, shell=use_shell)

    print(f"\nDone!\n{div}\n")

else:
    print(f"\nDone! - No unused dependencies found.\n{div}\n")
```