# Too many dev dependencies in my package.json

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, package.json

The projet that I am working on was touched by many developers. I see many dev dependencies in package.json. How can I know which one is not used ? which one can i remove ?.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
    "@cypress/vue": "^2.2.3",
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^8.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "cypress": "^9.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "jest-junit": "^13.0.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "vue": "2.6.14",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-server-renderer": "2.6.14"
  }
```

Comment: You have to check inside your project's source code which of those packages are using and run `npm un` for not used packages. There is also an automatic way to do this but I didn't try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65624518/8890700

Comment: You can safely remove all `cypress` and `jest` related packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a package called [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.org/package/depcheck).

**Install the package:**

```
npm install depcheck -g
```

**Or:**

```
yarn global add depcheck
```

Now run it and find unused dependencies and dev dependencies:

```
depcheck
```

Or you can use it with `npx` directly:

```
npx depcheck
```